# Filling a 2d array using a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with filling a 2d array using a for loop in javascript.

```js
var myArray = [[],[]];

var x = 0;
var z = 0;
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
        myArray[x][z] = "x"+x+"z"+z;
    }
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: What is your problem?  Please explain what you expect, and what you get.

Comment: Just be attentive. You forgot about `let` (or `var`) keyword during _loop variable_ declaration.

Comment: Just a word of advise, give preference to .push() method to prevent out of bound errors. Plus that kind of declaration is not acceptable for JS

Comment: @Aykhan - JavaScript arrays don't have out-of-bounds errors. I'm not sure what you mean by *"that kind of declaration is not acceptable for JS"*. The OP's code is syntactically correct, and `[[], []]` is a perfectly acceptable way to create an array containing two arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have two-dimensional arrays. It has arrays of arrays.¹ The problem in your code is that you've only created two of the inner arrays, not the other eight.

The solution is to create the inner arrays *inside* your `x` loop:

```js
var myArray = []; // *** Just create the outer

var x = 0;
var z = 0;
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    myArray[x] = []; // *** Create inner here
    for (z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
        myArray[x][z] = "x"+x+"z"+z;
    }
}

console.log(myArray);
```

---

¹ More generally, it doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, it has arrays of arrays (of arrays (of arrays (of...))). :-)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that javascript doesn't have multidimensional arrays.