# Getting error while converting string to integer TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface

Can anyone please help me to understand, why I'm getting this error for the code below:

```
let _board = [];
let size = 3;

  for (let i = 0, k = 2; i < size * size; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < size * size; j++) {
      _board[i][j] = parseInt(process.argv[k]);
      k++;
    }
  }

console.log(_board);
```

**What I want to do**

- I am trying to take string input from the CLI and convert that string into 9x9 2d Integer array.
- As suggested in below solutions I have also done the initialization for _board array.

I have already tried solutions given to the below questions. But unfortunately, the issue still persists.

1. [Cannot set property '0' of 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534323/cannot-set-property-0-of-2d-array)
2. [How to fix “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574254/how-to-fix-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-0-of-undefined)
3. [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673237/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-0-of-undefined)

Comment: `_board[0]` is `undefined` and it should be an array / object instead to be able to access `_board[0][0]`.

Comment: `let _board = [];` just creates the outer array. Inside the outer `for` loop, you need `_board[i] = [];` to create the *inner* arrays. (JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, it has arrays that can contain arrays.) See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021319/filling-a-2d-array-using-a-for-loop-in-javascript)'s answers for details.